# Is slf4j affected by log4shell?

Tags: log4j, log4shell

Everyone is looking at log4j.  Is the slf4j framework actually also affected by log4shell?
I haven't found anything about it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please read their official statement
http://slf4j.org/log4shell.html

in short: SLF4J is just a logging API, if your actual binding uses an affected log4j version then you're "in".